# Is it possible to use the same object in multiple files?

Tags: python, object, global-variables, instantiation

I am new to coding in Python and I am trying to create a game using objects. In *main.py* I have created objects which represent a specific room using a class called *Room*. Can I instantiate these objects in a separate file and then use them in *main.py*? If it is possible, how do I do it?

I tried simply creating an object in a file and using it in *main.py*, but it did not work. I also tried making a method in a second file that creates a room object, and then called it in *main.py*, but that too did not work. I am also unable to find any documentation regarding using an object in multiple files.

This is an example of a room object:

```
dining_hall = Room("Dining Hall")
dining_hall.set_description("A large room with ornate golden decorations on each wall")
```

This is the constructor of the room class:

```
def __init__(self, room_name):
    self.name = room_name
    self.description = None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can instantiate objects in separate files. Also both ways you used are proper by description. Unfortunately i do not see full code you wrote, so can't tell what was wrong exactly. Here are two samples how you can achieve your goal:

Using object from another file:

**dining_hall.py**

```
dining_hall = Room("Dining Hall")
```

**main.py**

```
from dining_hall import dining_hall

dining_hall.set_description("A large room with ornate golden decorations on each wall")
```

Or you can use special instantiation function (better to implement something like singleton):

**dining_hall.py**

```
dining_hall_object = None

def get_dining_hall():
    global dining_hall_object

    if dining_hall_object is None:
        dining_hall_object = Room("Dining Hall")

    return dining_hall_object
```

**main.py**

```
from dining_hall import get_dining_hall

dining_hall = get_dining_hall()
dining_hall.set_description("A large room with ornate golden decorations on each wall")
```

Comment: Your first solution worked. I did not know that you could import an object from a file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For the second solution it is giving me the following error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dining_hall_object' referenced before assignment

Comment: I missed to declare variable global, my fault. Changed my response to working one

Answer (score 1):

In general you will want to define/implement your classes in the "separate" file and then initialise the object instances in a main script, which may or may not be called main.

room.py

```
class Room:

  def __init__(self, room_name):
    ...
```

main.py
(make sure that the folder containing room.py is in your path)

```
from room import Room

dining_hall = Room("Dining Hall")
...
```

Maybe you can explain why you want to initialise in another script - for example you might want "Dining Hall" to already know about its description, or you may want to enforce "Dining Hall" is unique? There are design patterns for these sorts of problems but I would need to know more of what you are trying to achive.

Comment: I want "Dining Hall" to already know about its description so that it takes up less space in my main file. I have already defined my object in the Room class, and I want to create an instance of the Room class in a different file and then use that instance in the main file.